# How to use Python requests module and TeamCity API to trigger a build?

Tags: python, post, build, teamcity, python-requests

There is a cURL example in section `Triggering a Build` of [TeamCity 9.x Documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-TriggeringaBuild):

`curl -v -u user:password http://teamcity.server.url:8111/app/rest/buildQueue --request POST --header "Content-Type:application/xml" --data-binary @build.xml`

I'd like to know how to convert it into an equivalent Python script (using `POST` request from the `requests` module)?

---

BTW, I tried the following Python script but got such a response code `400 (Bad Request)`:

```
url = "http://myteamcity.com:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/buildQueue/"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
data = json.dumps({'buildTypeId': 'MyTestBuild'})
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, auth=("username", "password"), timeout=10)
print "r = ", r

>> r =  <Response [400]>
```

If change the `Content-Type` in `headers` into `Accept`, got another response code `415 (Unsupported Media Type)`:

```
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}

>> r =  <Response [415]>
```

Comment: The curl example sends *XML*, not JSON. Why are you trying to *send* JSON?

Comment: The documentation is a bit of a mess; it seems to me that that API endpoint can *only* accept XML in the POST body.

Comment: As far as I know, requests module uses json data format, as shown in the documentation: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: That's just an example. Just send XML instead.

Comment: Hi, Martijn, thank you so much! It works if sending XML data, :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for triggering a build shows you need to send *XML*, not JSON:

```xml
<build>
    <buildType id="buildConfID"/>
</build>
```

The TeamCity REST API is a bit of a mixed bag; some methods accept both XML and JSON, some only accept XML. This is one of those latter methods. They'll respond with either XML or JSON, based on what you set the `Accept` header to.

Send the above with your required build ID; for an XML document that simply you could use templating:

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import quoteattr

template = '<build><buildType id={id}/></build>'

url = "http://myteamcity.com:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/buildQueue/"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
build_id = 'MyTestBuild'
data = template.format(id=quoteattr(build_id))

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, auth=("username", "password"), timeout=10)
```

Note that I used the [`xml.sax.saxutils.quotattr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.utils.html#xml.sax.saxutils.quoteattr) to make sure the value of `build_id` is properly quoted for inclusion as a XML attribute.

This'll produce XML; add `'Accept': 'application/json'` to the `headers` dictionary if you want to process a JSON response.

Comment: Martijn, thank you very much! 
Before I saw your solution, I specified the data as: `data = "<build><buildType id=\"MyTestBuild\"/></build>"`. 
For

Comment: If the data become more complicated, my simple method is error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

FYI json request works in TeamCity 10.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was written & answered, a contemporary OSS alternative now exists: [pyteamcity](https://github.com/SurveyMonkey/pyteamcity).

Pip command to install (or add `pyteamcity` to requirements.txt, etc.)

```sh
pip install pyteamcity
```

Code:

```py
from pyteamcity import TeamCity
tc = TeamCity('username', 'password', 'server', 'port')
result = tc.trigger_build('build_id')
print(f'Build triggered. Web URL: {result['webUrl']}')
```